# video Player not working in Xcode 4.2

Tags: objective-c

`i am facing problem to develop a code for running a mp4 video in ios5 Xcode programing.
   When i run app noting is display although clip2.mp4 file is in my bundle.please give me a
        proper solution

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
   [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                 pathForResource:@"clip2"
                 ofType:@"mp4"];
 player =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
   initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
  [player prepareToPlay];
   [player play];    


   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
   selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)                                                 
   name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
   object:player];

  //---play movie---

 }

   - (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
  MPMoviePlayerController *play= [aNotification object];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
   removeObserver:self
    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
    object:play];    
   /    / [player autorelease];    
   } `
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
```

`url` is already an `NSURL`. `-fileURLWithPath:` is used to create an `NSURL` from an `NSString` that contains a file path (i.e. `/path/to/file`) rather than a normal URL (i.e. `http://stackoverflow.com/`)